# I want to know SML code's return value

Tags: exception, sml

I have SML code.

```
fun f(0) = 1
  | f(1) = raise Odd
  | f(3) = f(3-2)
  | f(n) = (f(n-2) handle Odd => ~n)
```

The problem is that when f(11) is called f(9),f(7),...... are called.
And there is a precondition that "if f calls g and g raises an exception that f does not handle, then activation record of f is popped off the stack without returning control to the function f.".
What is returning value? I think it is -5, but can't be sure about that.

Comment: Did you *evaluate* `f(11)`? I'm not sure what the source of your uncertainty is.

Comment: When I execute that error masseage was occured. I don't know exactly why this happned.

Comment: What error message? Your question doesn't mention any error message (the quote you gave isn't like any SML error message I've ever seen).  Did you define `exception Odd`? I presumed that you did, but if you hadn't then put the line `exception Odd` *before* the function definition and it will compile and run as expected. It gives ~5 when run in SML/NJ.